# Outlook REST API - App Registration

Tags: api, email, outlook, google-api, outlook-restapi

I have a app using Google API to access my user's mailbox. I am trying to do the same using the Outlook REST API to extend my audience to Hotmail  & Live users.

The thing is I've been looking everywhere without finding a clear explanation on how to register an app. Do I need to pay for something? What kind of account do I need? What are the available scopes?

If someone can provide me with a short explanation on the steps to follow it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's free. You can use a free Microsoft Account to register at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. Look at the **Registering an app** section of https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted.

Comment: Thanks. Would add https://github.com/jasonjoh?tab=repositories. Super useful repositories around Outlook API

Comment: @justberare: Hi, can you tell me if  I need an Office 365 license for an android app that displays some meeting room users' calendar or an Outlook account from work is enough? I'm quite confused. Thanks!